# What is the height of iPad status bar?

Tags: ipad, height, statusbar

It is 20 pixels in iphones, but what is the height of status bar on iPad? I am thinking that it's 20 pixels because the views which I am making are of size 768 * 1004.

Comment: just to clarify, from Apple's docs: the difference between points vs pixels: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2ddrawing/conceptual/drawingprintingios/graphicsdrawingoverview/graphicsdrawingoverview.html

Comment: In special situations, such as sharing the connection on an iPhone, the status bar will double in width. I'm not sure if this happens on the iPad but I would advise caution.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You are right, 20 pixel on the iPad. See also [this forum posting](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=937836) for further links to back that claim up.

Comment: There is a space in the status bar of ipad, which is in Newsstand->ipad app. The space is below network, time and battery. How should I reduce the unncessary white space below these.

Answer (score 11):

The status bar is 40 pixels tall on all devices with Retina display, and 20 pixels tall on all older devices.

Note that this is always equivalent to 20 points, because 1 point is 2 pixels on a Retina display or 1 pixel on a non-Retina display. You can find further information on how points and pixels are handled in [Apple's iOS Drawing Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/GraphicsDrawingOverview/GraphicsDrawingOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010156-CH14-SW7).

Answer (score 4):

It is 20 pixels on the iPad as well.

Answer (score 3):

It's always 20 pixels, regardless of Retina or not due to how DPI works. The above answer could cause a lot of confusion, so I felt I should clear it up.

Comment: Can you explain that a bit further? I'm not getting the curve between "always 20 pixels", DPI and the different screen resolutions of Retina and non-Retina displays. Thanks.

Update: maybe you mixed-up px and pt?

Comment: It's always 20 _points_, but that's 40 pixels on retina displays.

Comment: To clarify further, 20 points equals 20 dip (device independent pixels) which means that the actual pixels used depend on the dip times the device-pixel-ratio (classic displays are 1x, retina was 2x and newer displays are 2x, 2.5x and higher)

http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/04/a_pixel_is_not.html